# Prevent all default gestures on iPad Safari

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, gestures

How to disable all default gestures on Safari on iPad using plain javascript. 
I have tried using `event.preventDefault();` for every event but it isn't working.
I run the app in the Safari and I want to disable all default touch events(gestures) and override with my own. I've also tried using a popular library hammer.js which has an option prevent_default but that doesn't work.

Comment: Why would you do that? Is there any other reason than to annoy the users?

Comment: Because I have an application that uses drag for example and when I want to drag my object the Safari drag is bothering me

Comment: I think you don't understand me. For example. I have a canvas where i preform operations on images. If I want to drag my picture that is not possible because the browser drags instead of the image. Do you understand? Sory for the bad explenation.

Comment: Have you find a solution to this problem, I got the same issue.

Comment: Me too, rotate & zoom an image on the page using js with 2 fingers will trigger the native zoom behavior to zoom the entire page, that is not the expected result.

Answer (score 3):

Preventing scrolling:

```
document.ontouchmove = function(event){
event.preventDefault();}
```

Preventing tap:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0"/>
```

Comment: I'll try to add more as I find any sollutions.

Answer (score 0):

I think your question is not clear enough (please change it). Do you mean that you have an iOS app with a UIWebView and you want do disable all mouse interactions on that UIWebView? If so, then indeed you must disable scrolling with something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
touchMove = function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
}
</script>
```

UIWebViews will not pass on touches and guestures to the view below. If you want to handle touches in native code, then just add a Wildcard GestureRecognizer to the UIWebView. Below you can see a helper class that you can use. You can use that on a UIWebView by calling:

```
[[WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder alloc] initWithController:self andView:self.webview];
```

In your project add the WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder.h with the following code:

```
    #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

typedef void (^TouchesEventBlock)(NSSet * touches, UIEvent * event);

@interface WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder : UIGestureRecognizer

@property(nonatomic,assign) UIView *forwardFrom;
@property(nonatomic,assign) UIViewController *forwardTo;

-(void) initWithController:(UIViewController*)theViewController andView:(UIView*)theView;
@end
```

Also add the file WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder.m with the folowing code:

```
#import "WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder.h"

@implementation WildcardGestureRecognizerForwarder

-(id) init {
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        self.cancelsTouchesInView = NO;
    }
    return self;
}

-(void) initWithController:(id)theViewController andView:(UIView*)theView {
    if ([self init]) {
        self.forwardFrom = theView;
        self.forwardTo = theViewController;
        [theView addGestureRecognizer:self];
        self.delegate = theViewController;
    }
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.forwardTo)
        [self.forwardTo touchesBegan:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesCancelled:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.forwardTo)
        [self.forwardTo touchesCancelled:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.forwardTo)
        [self.forwardTo touchesEnded:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.forwardTo)
        [self.forwardTo touchesMoved:touches withEvent:event];
}

- (void)reset
{
}

- (void)ignoreTouch:(UITouch *)touch forEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
}

- (BOOL)canBePreventedByGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventingGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

- (BOOL)canPreventGestureRecognizer:(UIGestureRecognizer *)preventedGestureRecognizer
{
    return NO;
}

@end
```